# New Bugs or New Features in MinGW?

Tags: c++, windows, g++, mingw

GCC 13.2.0, MinGW-w64

It Can't distinguish tabs from spaces!!!

For example, if you use tabs to indent, GCC will not give you the correct column number.

like this:

```cpp
\t#error //please replace '\t' to tabs!
```

You can try this.

[2024-02-09-1.png](https://www.z4a.net/images/2024/02/09/-2024-02-09-201015.png)

GCC will report:

[2024-02-09-0.png](https://www.z4a.net/images/2024/02/09/-2024-02-09-200646.png)

However, I'm really using tabs to indent!

I tried G++ 10.3.0 MSYS, That didn't make this mistake.

Comment: tab display size is generally configurable in editor...

Comment: Try setting the compiler option: `-ftabstop=width` - "_...Set the distance between tab stops. This helps the preprocessor report correct column numbers in warnings or errors,..."_ see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html

Answer (score 4):

A tab is just one single character. The column number presented by GCC in error messages generally only counts the number of characters.

In any case, GCC can't reliably tell you anything about the column in the sense of the presentation of these characters. GCC doesn't know how your terminal or editor/IDE will present the character sequence it outputs.

The presentation might not even be in monospace font, so that there isn't even a consistent meaning of "column" in the presentation. Even if the presentation is in a monospace font, then the width of a tab is not standardized and also up to the presenting terminal/application.

However, as noted in the comments under the question, there is an option `-ftabstop=` for GCC to make it treat tabs as a specified number of columns in the error reporting. According to documentation that is set to `8` by default, i.e. it should treat tabs as `8` characters for purpose of counting in error reporting. But that doesn't have to correlate to the actual width used in the presentation and it may be changed from the default.